# How there is can be 15°C Difference between Core 1 and Core 2

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, motherboard, temperature

My Laptop is MSI GE62VR-7RF with following specifications:

- Intel i7-7700HQ
- Nvidia GTX 1060
- 16GB DDR4 RAM

I bought my laptop in February 2017 and it runs pretty well for a month until some of my keyboard wont didn't register keypress, fortunatelly the MSI Service Center ( which in indonesia MSI affiliate with Datascrip to deal with any after sales service) accept my warranty clam so they replace the keyboard for free.

Since then my notebook is no longer able to sustain its Maximum 4 Cores Active CPU Clock speed, at first it just dropped slightly to 3Ghz butn few weeks later I just realized that now My laptop is no longer able to sustain it's CPU Base Clock (2.8Ghz) and dropped to 2.1Ghz. Now I realized that my problem is quite serious, its un-usual for gaming laptop to throttled down below its Maximum Clock speed and it is really unusual for laptop to throttled down to below its Base clock.

The reason why I didn't bring it immediately because the process on Datascrip is so long, it takes 5 weeks from the day I hand the laptop to the day I received my laptop. But this time the problem is pretty severe, I can't run any games without getting lags, So I make an another claim, this time is about the Cooling, and then as expected it takes 8 weeks, I don't know either I didn't give them clear enough explanation or they didn't understand whats hapened in my notebook but I see on notice that they replaced the Motherboard, and that didn't really addressed the issue, my notebook are still suffering overheating issue  and then my Windows 10 Pro key activation aren't recognized.

After that warranty clam, my notebook can reach again its maximum 4 cores active clock speed but it is on 95°C, so I decided to to undervolt my by 140 mv offset, and that lower my core #1 temp to 88°C even at full load, overtime my cooling gradually getting less and less effective, today it only able to sustain at 2.90Ghz with 95°C Core 1 temperature with lowest possible voltage And I realized that there is huge temperature difference between Core 1 and Core 2. Now I'm confused which is my component is defective.

**What is the possible reason how there is a huge gap of temperature between core#1 and core#2**

[image: My XTU Screenshot]

**Extra Detail**: Only the CPU suffered this problem, my GPU is just running well at 85°C at Max.

Comment: What other tools have you used to verify the temperature of the core?  Your hardware in general is running extremely hot.

Comment: I didn't verify the temperature of the core, I don't know whatever the XTU temp report is accurate. However i think it's its no matter it is actually really hot or just CPU temperature false reading, because they both ruined my laptop CPU performance. My laptop is still under warranty so I can't open the cover without void the warranty.

Comment: You should run multiple tools to verify the accuracy but like I did your machine is running hot even at full load.

Comment: I want to do that, but if I disassemble my laptop, it will void the warranty. I think it's better to wait till July to claim my warranty again but at MSI Service Center in Singapore, I hope their technician can really solve that problem and not just blindly issue a motherboard replacement without analyzing the problem first like the Technician in here did. Do you have idea what is the possible causes that make my notebook so easily get overheated.

Comment: Why are you going to disassemble anything.  I am asking you to run software

Comment: “Do you have idea what is the possible causes that make my notebook so easily get overheated.“ - Airflow

Comment: Oh sorry. So far I have check it with XTU and HWInfo, and both of them give pretty similar reading with just 2 Celsius difference at furthest difference and generally just give same reading. I forgot to add the weird things about that is, as soon as I stopped the load the CPU temperature instantly cooled down from 95 to 60 in just a second, I think it's nearly impossible as my GPU need more than 2 minutes to get cool down from 85 to 63.

Comment: I suggest you request a motherboard replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Are you sure about that, they have replaced the motherboard in my last warranty claim 5 months ago. I don't know how changing the motherboard will fix that issue. But I'll consider about your suggestion.

Comment: You actually need to replace your processor, since you can't do that nor will the Service Center do that, a replacement motherboard is your only solution.  The service center is NOT going to desolder your processor and resolder a replacement.  **That is to labor intensive.**